# Trigger Mysql Procedure from Airflow

Tags: mysql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to trigger a stored procedure in Mysql from Airflow DAG using below code:

```
run_this_first = airflow.operators.mysql_operator.MySqlOperator(
    task_id= 'sql_task',
    sql= 'call test_procedure()',
    mysql_conn_id= 'my_db',
    database= 'my_db_schema_name',
    dag = dag)
```

DAG compiles successfully and on starting task from UI, it keeps running and nothing is updated in database. 
Scheduler is up and running.

What can be wrong ?

Also from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46359497/how-to-obtain-and-process-mysql-records-using-airflow), I am trying to understand difference between hook and operator.

Comment: Resolved as per [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047832/3098658). Missed to "Turn On" from Web UI.

Comment: So were you able to run stored procedures from airflow? I ask because I'm running into a problem where the tasks are being marked  as complete in Airflow but I'm not seeing any changes in the DB

Comment: Seen in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455029/run-stored-procedure-in-airflow) some possible answer. Worth trying.