# Run Stored Procedure in Airflow

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, automation, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I try to run my stored procedure in Airflow. Simply, I imported mssql operator and tried to execute following:

```
sql_command = """ EXEC [spAirflowTest] """
t3 = MsSqlOperator( task_id = 'run_test_proc',
                    mssql_conn_id = 'FIConnection',
                    sql = sql_command,
                    dag = dag,
                    database = 'RDW')
```

It completes this task as successful. However, task is not even executed. Because I get no error from system, I also cannot identify the error. To identify whether it arrived to my microsoft sql server, I checked with data profiling and it seems like server gets the command but does not execute it. Indeed, I can see sql command in data profiling tool.

When I run command for reading something, like :

```
select *
from sys.tables
```

it returns successful, also, with result. How can I solve this problem? Is there anyone who encountered with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql_command = """ EXEC [spAirflowTest] """
t3 = MsSqlOperator( task_id = 'run_test_proc',
                    mssql_conn_id = 'FIConnection',
                    sql = sql_command,
                    dag = dag,
                    database = 'RDW',
                    autocommit = True)
```

adding autocommit as above solved the issue